# Flex ItemRenderer as CheckBox

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have an itemRenderer as CheckBox in a Flex DataGrid.

Now, I want to make sure that **only one checkbox is selected at a time**. If user select's a checkbox, and then tries to select another checkbox, previous selection should be cancelled out.

How to do in Flex ?

**EDIT :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">



    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.CheckBox;
            import mx.controls.RadioButton;
            import mx.controls.RadioButtonGroup;

            [Bindable]
            protected var renderer:ClassFactory;

            protected function initRenderer() {
                var group:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup();
                var renderer = new ClassFactory(RadioButton);
                renderer.properties = {group:group};
            }

            private var arrayC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection
                (
                    [
                        {fname:"Person1",isSelected:false},
                        {fname:"Person2",isSelected:false},
                        {fname:"Person3",isSelected:false}
                    ]
                );

                    // To be called when we uncheck checkbox ..
            private function unSelect(event:MouseEvent):void {

            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:DataGrid id="dg" x="400" y="400" dataProvider="{arrayC}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn id="dgc1" itemRenderer="{renderer}"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn id="dgc2" dataField="fname"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[Bindable]
protected var renderer:ClassFactory;

protected function initRenderer() {
   var group:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup();
   var renderer = new ClassFactory(RadioButton);
   renderer.properties = {group:group};
}
```

Bind your column's itemRenderer property to renderer.

EDIT:
There was originally another answer on this post that explained that it is not really a good idea to use a check box when the functionality needed is what useres will expect from Radio Buttons. Users expect when they see check boxes that they can check more than one. http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20040927.html

Comment: I want my checkboxes to function like RadioButton ..where to write this code ?

Comment: and what is `{group:group}` here ?

Comment: Use the icon style of the RadioButton to make it look like a Check box.  Or write your own CheckBox Class.

Comment: That will set the group property on each Renderer as it is "born" to your RadioButtonGroup.

Comment: You don't need to call unSelect(), because by using a RadioButtonGroup, it will deselect the other radio buttons. You might need to override some properteries in a RadioButton subClass to get the selection to reflect in the data (and vice versa), but that's not the question you asked. The CheckBox and RadioButton should actually just handle this, but they're not written correctly to implement IDropInListItemRenderer.

Comment: My comments on this post may point you to the best way to override some of the functions that you'll need to look at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=celleditor_4.html